# Redhat | Openssl installation error

Tags: redhat, openssl

```
make -f objs/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/fuse-ssh/nginx-0.7.65' 
cd /usr/bin/openssl \
        && make clean \
        && ./config --prefix=/usr/bin/openssl/.openssl no-shared  no-threads \
        && make \
        && make install
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /usr/bin/openssl: Not a directory
make[1]: *** [/usr/bin/openssl/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/fuse-ssh/nginx-0.7.65'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

where's the actual location of openssl, there are several different places in my system.. How to solve this issue.

```
rpm -ql openssl

/usr/bin/openssl
/usr/lib64/openssl
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/lib4758cca.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libaep.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libatalla.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libchil.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcswift.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libgmp.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libnuron.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libsureware.so
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libubsec.so
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/INSTALL
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/README
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/README.FIPS
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/c-indentation.el
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/openssl.txt
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/openssl_button.gif
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/openssl_button.html
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/ssleay.txt
/usr/bin/openssl
/usr/lib/openssl
/usr/lib/openssl/engines
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/lib4758cca.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libaep.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libatalla.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libchil.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libcswift.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libgmp.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libnuron.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libsureware.so
/usr/lib/openssl/engines/libubsec.so
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/CHANGES
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/INSTALL
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/README
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/README.FIPS
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/c-indentation.el
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/openssl.txt
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/openssl_button.gif
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/openssl_button.html
/usr/share/doc/openssl-0.9.8e/ssleay.txt
```

These are the places..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /usr/bin/openssl: Not a directory`

..means exactly that, you are trying to change directories to a directory that doesn't exist. /usr/bin/openssl is a binary file. What exactly are you trying to do, compile openssl or nginx?

Comment: I'm trying to compile nginx

Comment: I didn't install openssl, because in Redhat it's already there.. so is this issue with the version ?

Comment: problem solved I followed the official installation guide

Comment: Im having the exact same problem, which guide are you following? thanks